# Google App Engine get and post on the same model

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications

I am new to google app engine/webapp and trying to get a simple app running. The app will be for a demo car rental service. I would like to have a request handler for adding new cars that handles both a get and a post for the add car page.

The get should return a form to be filled and submitted. The post should add the car (I am not worried about this yet) and then return a similar page with a form and 'car successfully added' or something similar.

Here was my approach:

URL Mapping:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/employee/add/car', AddCar)],
                                      debug=True)
```

AddCar:

```
class AddCar(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(template.render('templates/addcar.html', {}))

    def post(self):
        self.response.out.write(template.render('templates/addcarsuccess.html', {}))
```

addcar.html Template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>Add a Car</h2>

    <form action="/employee/add/car" method="post">
        <label>Make</label>
        <input type="text" name="make"></input>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit"></input>
    </form>
{% endblock body %}
```

I get a `405 Method Not Allowed` response when I submit the form shown above.

I tried doing prints, raising exceptions, etc in the post function just to see if it is being called and it doesn't look like it is.

I tried pulling the post out into a separate class and that seemed to work, but I would rather have them in the same handler.

I hope that I am missing something simple that will let me accomplish this.

Any Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks right to me. Perhaps there's a spacing/indentation issue. You might try moving the post method above the get to see if there's any change in behavior.

Comment: I moved the post above the get and started getting indentation errors in the get function. So I rewrote it using spaces and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tested your code and is correct, my guess is that the original `post` method in your code has some indentation error.

Comment: Looks like it was the indentation. I rewrote it using spaces and it worked. I am surprised it didn't throw an indentation exception. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @Jsch it didn't throw the indentation error probably because, due to the indentation error, the `post` method was declared inside the `get` method body.